# Cannot send CAN messages between two arduino

Tags: c, arduino, raspberry-pi, embedded, can-bus

I'm trying to set up local CAN bus between two Arduino boards (mega and pro micro). But I cannot make them receive any message from each other...

For both boards, I'm using this CAN module: [https://www.amazon.com/CHENBO-Electronics-Receiver-Controller-Development/dp/B015W4D9WY/ref=sr_1_3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B015W4D9WY)

The connection between the Arduino board and CAN is done in the following way:

ProMicro:

- VCC on the module - VCC from micro
- GND on the module - GND from micro
- CS on the module -PIN 10 on board
- SO on the module -PIN 14 on board
- SI on the module - PIN 16 on board
- SCK on the module - PIN 15 on board

Mega 2560:

- VCC on the module - 5V VCC from micro
- GND on the module - GND from micro
- CS on the module -PIN 53 on board
- SO on the module -PIN 50 on board
- SI on the module - PIN 51 on board
- SCK on the module - PIN 52 on board

Both boards are connected to the PC and attached to the Serial monitor.

I have also a raspberry PI for debugging purposes with this module: https://www.waveshare.com/rs485-can-hat.htm

From the software, I'm using this Arduino library: https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/CAN_BUS_Shield
and this one for Raspberry: https://github.com/sebi2k1/node-can

This is the code for Arduino micro:

```c
#define DEBUG_EN 1
#include <SPI.h>
#include "mcp_can.h"

const int SPI_CS_PIN = 10;

long unsigned int rxId;
unsigned char len = 0;
unsigned char buf[8];

long unsigned int txID = 0xF0;
unsigned char stmp[8] = {0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3};

MCP_CAN CAN(SPI_CS_PIN);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);

  while (CAN_OK != CAN.begin(CAN_500KBPS, MCP_8MHz))
  {
    Serial.println("CAN BUS Module Failed to Initialize");
    Serial.println("Retrying....");
    delay(200);
  }
  Serial.println("CAN BUS Module Initialized!");
  Serial.println("PGN\t\tByte0\tByte1\tByte2\tByte3\tByte4\tByte5\tByte6\tByte7");
}

void loop()
{
  if (CAN_MSGAVAIL == CAN.checkReceive())
  {
    Serial.println("I have something on micro...");
    CAN.readMsgBuf(&len, buf);
    rxId = CAN.getCanId();

    Serial.print("0x");
    Serial.print(rxId, HEX);
    Serial.print("\t");

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (buf[i] > 15)
      {
        Serial.print("0x");
        Serial.print(buf[i], HEX);
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.print("0x0");
        Serial.print(buf[i], HEX);
      }
      Serial.print("\t");
    }
    Serial.println();

    Serial.println("sending message...");
    CAN.sendMsgBuf(txID, 1, 8, stmp);
  }
}
```

Almost the same for Arduino mega:

```c
#include <mcp_can.h>
#include <SPI.h>

const int SPI_CS_PIN = 53;

unsigned char len = 0;
unsigned char buf[8];
long unsigned int rxId;

long unsigned int txID = 0xFF;
unsigned char stmp[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

MCP_CAN CAN(SPI_CS_PIN);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);

  while (CAN_OK != CAN.begin(CAN_500KBPS, MCP_8MHz))
  {
    Serial.println("CAN BUS Module Failed to Initialize");
    Serial.println("Retrying....");
    delay(200);
  }
  Serial.println("CAN BUS Module Initialized!");
  Serial.println("PGN\t\tByte0\tByte1\tByte2\tByte3\tByte4\tByte5\tByte6\tByte7");
}

void loop()
{
  if (CAN_MSGAVAIL == CAN.checkReceive())
  {
    Serial.println("I have something no mega...");
    CAN.readMsgBuf(&len, buf);
    rxId = CAN.getCanId();

    Serial.print("0x");
    Serial.print(rxId, HEX);
    Serial.print("\t");

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (buf[i] > 15)
      {
        Serial.print("0x");
        Serial.print(buf[i], HEX);
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.print("0x0");
        Serial.print(buf[i], HEX);
      }
      Serial.print("\t");
    }
    Serial.println();

    Serial.println("sending...");
    CAN.sendMsgBuf(txID, 1, 8, stmp);
  }
}
```

And debug code on raspberry:

```
var can = require("socketcan");

var channel = can.createRawChannel("can0", true);

// Log any message
channel.addListener("onMessage", function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});

channel.start();
console.log("Sending initial message...");
channel.send({id: 0x0F, ext: 1, rtr: false, data: Buffer.from([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])});
console.log("Listening to messages");
```

Before starting the test I'm executing those commands on Raspberry:

```
sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000
sudo ifconfig can0 up
```

And those are the outputs:

from Raspberry:

```
Sending initial message...
Listening to messages
{ ts_sec: 1560890627,
  ts_usec: 297829,
  id: 240,
  ext: true,
  data: <Buffer 00 09 08 07 06 05 04 03> }
{ ts_sec: 1560890627,
  ts_usec: 318244,
  id: 255,
  ext: true,
  data: <Buffer 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08> }
```

which means that both Arduino boards are sending correct data to CAN bus...

from Arduino Micro:

```
lib is working....
Enter setting mode success 
set rate success!!
Enter Normal Mode Success!!
CAN BUS Module Initialized!
PGN     Byte0   Byte1   Byte2   Byte3   Byte4   Byte5   Byte6   Byte7
I have something on micro...
0xF 0x01    0x01    0x01    0x01    0x01    0x01    0x01    0x01    
sending message...
```

Here I'm missing a message from Arduino Mega

and from Arduino Mega

```
lib is working....
Enter setting mode success 
set rate success!!
Enter Normal Mode Success!!
CAN BUS Module Initialized!
PGN     Byte0   Byte1   Byte2   Byte3   Byte4   Byte5   Byte6   Byte7
I have something no mega...
0xF 0x01    0x01    0x01    0x01    0x01    0x01    0x01    0x01    
sending...
```

Here also the problem is that there is no message from Arduino Micro

How I can make Arduino boards to receive all messages from the CAN bus?

Comment: From the MPC_CAN_lib github, it says : "The readMsgBuf() functions bring in the message ID. The getCanId() function is obsolete and no longer exists, don't use it.". Are you using an older version?

Comment: I'm using the newest version of https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/CAN_BUS_Shield/ it seems that https://github.com/coryjfowler/MCP_CAN_lib is some newer version of the lib. I'll try it tomorrow. Thanks for a suggestion

Comment: Sorry for late response, the new library (https://github.com/coryjfowler/MCP_CAN_lib) worked out of the box :) thank you :) I can write some more complete answer to this later